# Android: Unexpected recent apps behavior

Tags: android

Our app has 2 Activities- A `MainActivity` (associated with Launcher icon) and an `AuxActivity` for handling URI events.

I'm seeing an issue with this scenario, with my app initially exited:

1. Open Browser, click on a URI to launch the `AuxActivity`.
2. `AuxActivity` exits (calls finish()), user returns to Browser.
3. User brings up recent Apps (long-press home), and selects my app.

Instead of starting `MainActivity`, I'm seeing `AuxActivity` being started with the same intent that represents a URI click (`android.intent.action.VIEW`).

Now instead of step 3, if the user were to open my app through its Home Screen icon, I get back to `MainActivity`, as expected.

How can I get step 3 to launch `MainActivity` instead?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think you can make it point to the other activity, without some sort of logic in the auxActivity, that is somehow able to determine that MainActivity is what should've been launched, and forards the user to along to that Activity. I do think you can use some sort of manifest attribute and/or intent flag when starting the the auxActivity to make it not show up in that list of recently used apps though.(but I don't know what it is off the top of my head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tim's suggestion, what about adding

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

To the auxActivity listing in the Manifest? Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in AuxActivity's onCreate:

```
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) > 0) {
    // do something different e.g. launch MainActivity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but you might also try:

> android:noHistory="true"
>
> Whether or not the activity should be removed from
>   the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the
>   user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen —
>   "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value
>   is "false". A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a
>   historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the
>   task, so the user will not be able to return to it. This attribute was
>   introduced in API Level 3.